# C++ SFML. Некорректное отображение координат при движении мышью влево вправо

Tags: c++, ооп, sfml, координаты, мышь

Проблема такая: при быстром движении мыши влево вправо координаты мыши как-бы перескакивают на несколько пикселей x или y. Привожу пример (координата X высчитывается с пробелами 344,349,353,355... и тгд.)
Как можно решить данную проблему, чтобы координаты отображались корректно?

new mouse x: 344
new mouse y: 50
new mouse x: 349
new mouse y: 50
new mouse x: 353
new mouse y: 50
new mouse x: 355
new mouse y: 50
new mouse x: 357
new mouse y: 50
new mouse x: 358
new mouse y: 50
new mouse x: 359
new mouse y: 50
new mouse x: 360

Comment: Конечно они перескакивают. Опрос мыши же происходит через фиксированный интервал времени. Если мышь передвинется за это время далеко, то и координата следующего положения будет далеко. Это же не Древняя Греция.

Comment: Есть какие-нибудь способы увеличить опрос мыши?

Comment: Есть, но как бы быстро мышь не опрашивалась, всегда будет возможность появления скачков координат. Собственно из вопроса не ясно, чем это вас смущает.

Comment: Не могу нарисовать сплошную линию без разрывов. Придется делать костыль высчитывающий начальные и текущие координаты. И между ними вставлять значения.

Comment: Это не костыль, это называется интерполяция.